# Google Analytics: multiple domains graphic

Tags: google-analytics

I changed the code on some of my websites to track all data into one Google Analytics account. I did this by adding on every domain:

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'http://myurl.com']);
```

Now I see data appear in Google Analytics but I don't know how to display it correctly. I want the following to appear on my dashboard:

- Domain visitor report: a line graph of every domain's daily visitors
- Domain bounce rate report: a line graph of bounce rates / domain

This way I can easily see what my top domains are etc.

Is this even possible in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 'Behavior > Site Content > All Pages' report, you can switch the Primary Dimension to '[Hostname](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032966?hl=en)'